# How to plot data of by selecting diffrent patient_id from my database and plot graph on it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner at this.

If I'm inserting P001(patient_id) data in drop down select then it is taking P002 in dropdown but retrieving  P001 data from database that is from phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "connection.php";
?>
 <form  method="POST">
<div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <div class="title_left">
                        <h3>Realtime Patient Health Monitor</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title_right">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--FRONT ENDS-->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row" style="min-height:500px">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="x_panel">

                            <div class="x_content">
                               <label>Select Patient ID</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="patient_id">
         <?php 
         $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT patient_id from heart_reating");

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             echo "<option value='" . $row['patient_id'] . "'>" . $row['patient_id'] . "</option>";
         ?>
  </select>  

  <input  id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 

                                <?php
                                 if(isset($result)){
                                         $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating  limit 1");
                                 }
                           // $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
                         //   $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT patient_id, sdi, rate, temp, max, min, interv FROM heart_reating");
                           // echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
                            ?>
                            <col width=40>
                            <col width=50>
                            <col width=>
                            <col width=>
                            <col width=40>
                            <col width=40>
                            <col width=40>
                            <!--table properties close-->



                              <?php 
                                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>

                              <tr>

                              <div> 
                              <td >
                                  <iframe src="linegraph.html" height="620px" width="620px"></iframe>
                              </td>

                              <td><iframe src="new.html" height="620px" width="620px"></iframe></td>
                              </div>
                              <td><?php echo $row["max"] ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row["min"] ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row["interv"] ?></td>
                              </tr> 

                              <?php }}
                              ?>
  <!--<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>-->  
                            </table>
                            <?php
                        /*    echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Patient ID";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Sepses Detection Index(%)";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Heart Rate";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Temperature";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Max";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Interval";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "Min";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                            //variable declaration closed
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>";
                        //        $pid = $row["patient_id"];
                                echo $row["patient_id"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                echo $row["sdi"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>";?>
                                <style>
                              .chart-container {
                                width: 640px;
                                height: 300px;
                              }
                                </style>  
                            <!--    <div class="chart-container"> --> 
                            <!--   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas> -->
   <canvas class="chart-container" id="mycanvas"></canvas>  
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/Chart.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/linegraph.js">

    </script> 
                                <?php
                                echo $row["rate"];
                                echo "<td>";
                                echo $row["temp"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                echo $row["max"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                echo $row["interv"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                echo $row["min"];
                                echo "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>"; */
                            ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
                              <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                              <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/Chart.min.js"></script>
                              <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/linegraph.js"></script>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

When in drop down select if select patient id of 2nd it should plot graph of 2nd patient as of now its only showing graph on first column data.
I want where if I select other patient it should call that data and plot graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that when you select **patient Id** that you are not posting it to the backend php and hence 
not passed in the sql queries.

**Work round:**

Look for this line of code and that is where you are having issues

```
 if(isset($result)){
 $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating  limit 1");
 }
```

You will need to test it with directly with different patient_id values in the database to ensure its working
To test for **patient_id of 1**, it becomes

```
  $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating where patient_id= 1");
```

now to pass the patient_id from form to sql query

```
$patient_id= $_POST['patient_id']
$res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating where patient_id= '$patient_id'");
```

Oh yes, the above code is still vulnerable to sql injection attack so you will need to escape it with some function

```
mysqli_real_escape_string();
```

**Usage**

```
$patient_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['patient_id']);
```

where **$con** is the database connection  variables. yours can be **$list** or anything that you have implemented

**Updated section**

If I understand you correctly. you can use php session
in **monitor.php**

you can initiate sessions as follows inside php tags

```
<?php

//start sessions
session_start();

//set patient id to session
$patient_id= $_POST['patient_id'];

$_SESSION['patient_id'] = $patient_id;


?>
```

in **data.php**

you can do this

```
<?php

//start sessions
session_start();
$pid = $_SESSION['patient_id'];
echo $pid

You can now use it in a query in data.php eg

mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating where patient_id= '$pid'"); 

?>
```

Comment: but its still not solving my problem.
its still showing only graph of first pateint from database even in drop down if i select other pateint id it redirect to first entry.

Comment: can you echo/print patient_id and tell me what you have each time you select patient id from dropdown eg  echo $patient_id= $_POST['patient_id']

Comment: i have tried these its printing (P001) i.e patient id below it if i select it. but in drop down its reverting back to p002

Comment: wait!. are u sending it with ajax?

Comment: do you replace this line of code  $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating  limit 1");

Comment: with this     $patient_id= $_POST['patient_id']
$res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from heart_reating where patient_id= '$patient_id'");

Comment: can u please help me in one thing
see as you told suppose i have declared patient_id in one page (monitor.php) and graph js files are taking data from another page page(data.php) but now its plotting data on all data that include all patient_id but now i got where i went wrong 
now i'm connecting both pages page with include pagename.php  but now as we have to tell in data.php select temp,time from readings where patient_id = '$patient_id';  
how can i connect the $patient_id which i have declared in monitor.php to data.php sql query.

i think it will solve my issue

Comment: Please see updated section of my answer on what to do. I will also appreciate to upvote my answer if its useful to you. Thanks

Comment: You are getting me confused. when I click the link, it returns data in json arrays Your issues may be from followdata_temp.php which i do not have knowledge of. Again your code is not good feet for production as I can see alot of vulnerabilities in it. Data not escaped and validated. You will need to read  up about OWAPS top 10 web vulnerabilities and security measures. Thanks you

Comment: Even more ... They are alot to implement with .htaccess and php.in files for more security. You will need to read up how to secure php applications using .htaccess files and php.ini.  If a night hawk Hacker get hold of the site. you are gone.  Thank you

Comment: ok.. sorry i have asked you to much question and ty  for ur kind help i will improve my code as im new and is little aware  about php.. i will improve my site as per ur suggestion
thanx again